# .net core rate limit -- want to get remaining rate limit count

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, rate-limiting

I am using .Net Core 7 and implemented rate limiter. So I have limit user based on IP address.

It is working fine.. Now I want to see remaining permit limit to execute that API end point and I am trying below code for that.

But I am getting this error :

```
The Name GetLimiter does not exist in current context.
```

I am using below code :

```
RateLimiter limiter = GetLimiter();
using RateLimitLease lease = limiter.Acquire(permitCount: 1);
if (lease.IsAcquired)
{
    // Do action that is protected by limiter
}
else
{
    // Error handling or add retry logic
}
```

Comment: It seems you were trying a 3rd tool could you share it so that we could know whcih  limiter you were trying with?

Comment: Sure here is link for that `https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-rate-limiting-for-dotnet/`