# How to access response header values

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I am working in web api project using .Net Core 7

I am getting values in Response headers.. So I want to access that values in one variable.

Please see below screenshot, I want to get value of

```
x-rate-limit-remaining
```

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

```
try
{
    HttpClient client = new();
    using var response = await client.GetAsync(URL);
    var HeaderKey = "x-rate-limit-remaining";
    if (response.Headers.Contains(HeaderKey))
    {
        var val = response.Headers.GetValues(HeaderKey).FirstOrDefault();
        Console.WriteLine(val);
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"the key '{HeaderKey}' not found in the headers!");
    }
}
catch (Exception ee)
{
    Console.Error.WriteLine(ee.Message);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on your [former case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76348462/net-core-rate-limit-want-to-get-remaining-rate-limit-count)

You could try as below:

```
if (HttpContext.Response.Headers.ContainsKey("x-rate-limit-remaining"))
    {
        var header = HttpContext.Response.Headers["x-rate-limit-remaining"];
    }
```

For example in middleware :

```
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{

    
    if (context.Response.Headers.ContainsKey("x-rate-limit-remaining"))
    {
        var header = context.Response.Headers["x-rate-limit-remaining"];
    }
    
    await next.Invoke();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use TryGetValues with StringValues:

```
var headers = response.Headers;
string role = "";
if (headers.TryGetValues("Role", out Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.StringValues headerValues))
{
    role = headerValues.FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Or use IEnumerable:

```
var headers = response.Headers;
string role = "";
if (headers.TryGetValues("Role", out IEnumerable<string> headerValues))
{
    role = headerValues.FirstOrDefault();
}
```